# Upgrade from CE 1.9.1 to 1.9.2.2 produces "Can't retrieve entity config: admin/permission_block"

Tags: error

I have recently upgraded Magento CE from 1.9.1.1 to 1.9.2.2 and when I goto Admin > System > Permissions > Blocks, I receive an error screen with:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Can't retrieve entity config: admin/permission_block

How do I resolve this please?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, these steps solved it:

1- Make sure your tmp folder is writable, I had a custom tmp folder set on `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`

`'cache_dir' => 'tmp',`

2- Remove var/cache and reload the admin page